# Magento consuming a lot of memory on specific store view

Tags: magento-1.9, products, performance, debug, memory

I have a Magento store, with two store views, one for spanish language, and another one for english, so, I have this code:

```
//setting spanish store view
Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(8);

$time_start = microtime(true); 

$idProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku('487767');
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($idProduct);
echo $product->getSku() . PHP_EOL;

$time_end = microtime(true);
$execution_time = ($time_end - $time_start);
echo 'Total Execution Time:'.$execution_time.' Seconds'.PHP_EOL;
```

When I execute that I see this:

> Total Execution Time:0.12779498100281 Seconds

But when I choose a different store view:

```
 //setting english store view
Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(1);

$time_start = microtime(true); 

$idProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku('487767');
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($idProduct);
echo $product->getSku() . PHP_EOL;

$time_end = microtime(true);
$execution_time = ($time_end - $time_start);
echo 'Total Execution Time:'.$execution_time.' Seconds'.PHP_EOL;
```

The execution time is huge different:

> Total Execution Time:15.901492834091 Seconds

is consuming a lot of memory, **any way for track de SQL generated of "load" function or something?** Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually because the second store have way more products than the first one. But in your case I doubt that's the problem as they seems to be only language store views (they share the same products right ?)

It could be a problem with indexes, you should try enabling long query log to find out by setting `$_debug` to true in `lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php` and modifying the `$_logQueryTime` to find excessively long queries. Then you'll have to check the `var/debug/pdo_mysql.log` file to find out what's going on with the long sql queries.

### Recommendation

Try to avoid `load()` as much as possible. For instance your code can be optimized with the following code and you'll gain a lot of performance:

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(1);

$time_start = microtime(true); 

$productCol = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                  ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', '487767')
                  ->setPageSize(1);
$product = $productsCol->getFirstItem();
echo $product->getSku() . PHP_EOL;

$time_end = microtime(true);
$execution_time = ($time_end - $time_start);
echo 'Total Execution Time:'.$execution_time.' Seconds'.PHP_EOL;
```